# Randomly select elements from string in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have dataframe with 7 string columns:

```
bul; age; gender; hh; pn; freq_pn; rcrds_to_select

1;   2;     5;    1;  ['35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102'];4;3

2;   3;     3;    3;  ['06299501', '07694901', '35070201'];3;2
```

In the last column I have the number of id's from "pn" column that I need to select randomly. Example: in the first row I have 4 id's `['35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102']` and I need to select 3 random id's and remove the not selected one. There can be rows with only one id. I came to the conclusion that I need to turn the values in tuples and store them in another column (`'pnTuple'`). I don't know if this is the right way.

```
mass_grouped3['pnTuple'] = [tuple(x) for x in mass_grouped3['pn'].values]
```

I think `random.shuffle` will do the job, but have no idea how to implement it in my script. I was thinking something like this, but is not working:

```
for row in mass_grouped3['pnTuple']:
    list = list(mass_grouped3['pnTuple'])
    whitelist = random.shuffle(list)
```

Any ideas how to do this selection are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to randomly select 1 from every row and make the rest 0. Here's one approach. Sample the indices and based on indices assign 1. i.e

```
idx = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(np.where(df==1))).T.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).values
# array([[0, 2],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 0],
#        [3, 3]])

ndf = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(df.shape),columns=df.columns)

ndf.values[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = 1

   W1  W2  W3  W4
0   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Hope this helps

**Lets go step by step**

First lets construct our random function that can select 3

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choices(['35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102'], k=3)
['68229102', '40666303', '35784905']
```

I have a sample data frame, `df` with columns with same data as yours

```
>>> df
    a                                         b
0  12  [35784905, 40666303, 47603805, 68229102]
1  12            [06299501, 07694901, 35070201]

>>> df['b']
0    [35784905, 40666303, 47603805, 68229102]
1              [06299501, 07694901, 35070201]
Name: b, dtype: object

>>> df['b'].map(lambda alist: random.choices(alist, k=3) if len(alist) > 3 else alist)
0    [35784905, 68229102, 35784905]
1    [06299501, 07694901, 35070201]
Name: b, dtype: object

>>> df['b'] = df['b'].map(lambda alist: random.choices(alist, k=3) if len(alist) > 3 else alist)
```

Using pandas `map` operation to apply this data transformation to whole columns

**Note:** We are using a lambda function `lambda alist: random.choices(alist, k=3) if len(alist) > 3 else alist` to ensure that each list has more than 3 items, and only then apply this operation.

It might be a little new, but this a standard way of writing code in python. Learn more about Python, lambda function and pandas for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what I need is to read the value from 'rcrds_to_select' and use it as a 'k' in the function random. choices. And I want to do this for every row no matter how many items are in the tuple.

Comment: @Y.C.T - If you want to read every row and executed, please don't use a pandas data frame. Use the `csv` module to read rows as line and apply the same map function as shared above.